# Can't connect to MongoDB Atlas inside a Docker container

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, docker, docker-container, mongodb-atlas

I have a Spring Boot application running in a Docker container which is deployed on Google Cloud Run. For a few months this works perfectly fine. But now, without any action, my application can't connect to the MongoDB Atlas cluster anymore. I get the following error message:

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket at com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream$OpenChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(NettyStream.java:416)
```

If I run the application locally it works fine again. But if I run it inside a Docker container (also locally) I get the same error message.

Has anyone an idea what the problem can be? I've whitelist 0.0.0.0/0 on MongoDB Atlas so that the connection should work from everywhere.

Comment: Maybe its a simple port problem? What happens when you inspect the container?

Comment: Under "HostConfig" I get the following port infos: "PortBindings": {
                "8080/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "8080"
                    }
                ]
            }. And under "NetworkSettings" I get:  "Ports": {
                "8080/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "8080"
                    }
                ]
            }

Comment: getting same problem as well